# How to display unique records in a table using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display all unique records from table.

SQL Script:

```
CREATE TABLE certificate(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    full_name VARCHAR(200),
    address VARCHAR(200),
    date_of_birth DATETIME,
    special_code INT,
    validity VARCHAR(200)
);

INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('1','Walter White','Albuquerque 87107','1970-10-10','1000','VALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('2','Skyler White','Albuquerque 87107','1978-10-10','1001','VALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('3','Jesse Pinkman','Santa Fé 28','1979-10-10','1002','INVALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('4','Hank Schrader','El Paso 17','1980-10-10','1003','VALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('5','Hank Schrader','El Paso 17','1980-01-10','1004','VALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('6','Walter White','Albuquerque 87107','1970-10-10','1005','VALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('7','Saul Goodman','El Paso 14','1973-10-10','1006','VALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('8','Gustavo Fring','Santa Fé 190','1964-10-11','1007','INVALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('9','Walter White','Albuquerque 87107','1978-01-08','1008','VALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('10','Hank Schrader','El Paso 17','1980-10-10','1009','VALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('11','Walter White','Albuquerque 87107','1978-01-08','1010','VALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('12','Hank Schrader','El Paso 98','1980-10-10','10011','VALID');
INSERT INTO certificate VALUES('13','Hank Schrader','El Paso 98','1980-10-10','10012','VALID');
```

Queries:

The numbers of special code entries with valid certificates

```
select full_name, count(*) from certificate where validity = 'VALID' group by full_name;
```

All persons with valid certificates

```
select * from certificate where validity = 'VALID' order by full_name;
```

There are two people with this name but they live at a different address, so we can assume that it's not the same person and the result from first select is "incorrect"

```
select * from certificate where validity = 'VALID' and full_name = 'Hank Schrader';
```

In this selection there are three records belonging to two persons father and son.Both live at the same address but do not have the same date of birth result from first select is too "incorrect"

```
select * from certificate where validity = 'VALID' and full_name = 'Walter White';
```

So what I need:

- If the name is the same, I check the address with the other entries
  in the table with the same name.
- If the address is the same, I will
  check the date of birth with the other entries in the table with the
  same name.
- If this is the case, it is the same person, if not, the
  person is different and only

Then can I add the record.

Ultimately, I need a list of all unique people with their ids who have a valid certificate and have more than one entry in the table (Walter White with ID 11 does not represent the same person as Walter White with ID 8)

So result will be:

```
full_name     | ids
----------------------
Walter White  | 1,6
Walter White  | 9,11
Hank Schrader | 4,5,10
Hank Schrader | 12,13
```

The full code is available on:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71c251/1

Comment: How will you distinguish between Walter White and Walter White?

Comment: I distinguish it by address or date of birth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - use group by `full_name,address,date_of_birth`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b4910696f6b0234494ed2f186af8384)**

```
select full_name,
count(id) from certificate where validity = 'VALID'
group by full_name,address,date_of_birth having count(id)>1
```

Comment: And how can I get only the persons who have more than one record?

Comment: @AdyP, you can check, I've added the logic

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.full_name
     , x.date_of_birth
     , GROUP_CONCAT(y.id) aliases
  FROM certificate x
  JOIN certificate y
    ON y.full_name = x.full_name
   AND y.address = x.address
   AND y.date_of_birth = x.date_of_birth
   AND y.id >= x.id
 GROUP
    BY x.full_name
     , x.date_of_birth
HAVING COUNT(aliases) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry but the result is incorrect ...
`Hank Schrader | 1980-10-10T00:00:00Z | 4,10,10,12,13,13`